# Get wordpress post with featured image, category and tag from Wordpress API

Tags: rest-api, migration, json, cms

I have to transfer data from Wordpress website to custom CMS ( I don' t have access to database), and I need to transfer post data (title, excerpt, content) along with featured image link and category (preferably just category ID) if it' s possible using Wordpress API?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I need someone who can make query for API e.g. example.com/v2/json/posts=-1&meta_key=all&featured_image=url

Comment: It is possible, but it's unclear what your question is, are you asking how to query the API? How to use the endpoints? Please edit your question to make it specific.

Comment: I edited it :D. Thank you for your suggestion :D